# Application runs slower on Server

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I have a WinForms Application. I need to read data from very large binary files (>4GB). For this, I have chosen to use `MemoryMappedFile` concept. I am able to read the required data from the file. Following is a snippet of my memory mapped file:

```
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, "mf4");

// offset and blockLength vary on from where I want to read in the file.
var mmfStream = mmf.CreateViewStream(offset, BlockLength);
{
    using (BinaryReader mf4Reader = new BinaryReader(mmfStream))
    {
        // Reading required bytes using binary reader
    }
}
```

My application take around 6 minutes to read required data from the 4 GB file on a Windows 7 Professional PC (8GB RAM, Intel i5 Processor). But the same application is taking 11~16 minutes on a Windows Server 2012 with 4 times more the RAM and a better CPU. The number of users using the server is only 1.

I am totally stuck here and have no idea why it is like this. Any help/insight on usage of Memory Mapped File or Windows Server would be great.

**Update:**
I am using a c# dll in one of the modules in the project. When I added the source code of the dll and built the the solution the application now runs at same speed on the server too.

Comment: Your laptop got an SSD drive?

Comment: Nope..Same Kind of HDD on both server and laptop

Comment: @snaits: Server is also reading from local disk. Like I said, I am the only user.

Comment: Thats very unusual.. most servers are SCSI..or SAS   what OS is on the server, is the server virtual? does it have different AV?

Comment: The server is running on Windows Server 2012. What do you mean by Virtual Server and AV?

Comment: so you've not heard of virtualisation or antivirus??

Comment: I have Anti Virus on my laptop. Gotta check for virtualization

Comment: Check if your server is optimized for foreground applications: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/259025. Although the linked article describes Windows 2000, this still sems to be [applicable to Windows 2012](https://books.google.ru/books?id=0IyfBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT448&lpg=PT448&dq=windows+server+2012+background+applications+optimization&source=bl&ots=I5iu3DLVgp&sig=_K2KLMqD0mqZg09WUUtn5NZY4PA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPyu_RjtfOAhXPKCwKHYCIAe0Q6AEIRDAG#v=onepage&q=windows%20server%202012%20background%20applications%20optimization&f=false)

Comment: @DmitryEgorov: My server is set to adjust for best performance of programs.

Comment: @BugFinder: No Virtualization or no Anti Virus on the Server.

Comment: Then you'd need to do performance monitoring to see what the delay is

Comment: Even on your machine that's 10MB/sec which is super low. So it's likely CPU bound. Is the server CPU slower?

Comment: Also note that you are not deriving any benefit whatsoever from using MMF here. It's likely a bit worse (more overhead and worse IO patterns) than a FileStream with SeqScan.

Comment: The server cpu is octacore. A normal file stream will be able to handle 4-10gb size files?

Comment: You're likely only using one core. Is the server slower per-core? A file stream has no size limit. Why would it have one.